# Recursion before end of method not an infinite loop?

Tags: java, recursion

I understand tail recursion as it functions similarly to iteration, at the end of the method call itself with new parameters. But when a recursive call is placed before code at the end of the loop why does it not call it self infinitely? In the code below the method MergeSort_Recursive() calls itself twice within the same method. How would the second call to the method ever be reached? When the method is called the first time it would compare right > left and then initialize mid. Then it calls itself, and we go to the top of the method which would do right > left comparison again, initialize mid again, and then call itself again and continually repeat this step. I know of course that this not how it works, otherwise this method would fail. So my question is how does this work, and how do both methods ever end up getting called?

```
static public void MergeSort_Recursive(int [] numbers, int left, int right)
{
  int mid;

  if (right > left)
  {
    mid = (right + left) / 2;
    MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, left, mid);
    MergeSort_Recursive(numbers, (mid + 1), right);

    DoMerge(numbers, left, (mid+1), right);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could step through this with a debugger, and see for yourself why the recursion ends.

Answer (score 1):

There are base cases where `right > left` is false. Then, the function does *not* call itself a single time, so it successfully returns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, eventually you'll get it being called with `left` and `right` equal, so the `if` block won't be entered, and the recursion ends.

For example, if you call it with `left = 0, right = 4`, then the next call has `left = 0, right = 2`, then `left = 0, right = 1`, then finally `left = 0, right = 0`.  This last call doesn't recurse further.

To prove that the recursion ends, consider the gap between `left` and `right`.  This reduces every time, so it must eventually reach 0.  It reduces for the first call because `mid` is guaranteed to be `< right`, and it reduces for the second call because `mid + 1` is guaranteed to be `> left`.

Comment: So when left and right are equal the if block won't be entered. I understand that. But when is the second recursive call ever actually called?

Comment: Well, in the example that I gave, when you call with `left = 0, right = 4`, the second call has `left = 3, right = 4`.  Its second call has `left = 4, right = 4` and the recursion ends.

Comment: Very good explanation. +1. You even partially explained the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the

```
if (right > left)
```

This prevents the recursion from continuing when `right <= left` (actually, `right` is never less than `left`, so it stops when `right == left`). It is sort of like the `i > 0` in a for loop.

Comment: Actually, it's the case where `right == left` that stops the recursion, not `right < left`.

Comment: Or, you could put `==` which would be more accurate.